# Enemy Script Isn't working properly on my Tower Defense game c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've recently been following a tutorial from "Brackeys" on youtube for a tower defence game, I followed it word for word but have an error (which is on the photos below) that won't let my enemy prefabs move in the scene. The prefabs are all spawning, but are stuck in the one spot.
any help will be appreciated

thanks, Mitch

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    private Transform target;
    private int wavePointIndex = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() 
    {
        // An error pops up on the first frame for this line of code below
        target = Waypoints.points[0];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        // This is the main source of the error below.
        Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
        transform.Translate (dir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        if (Vector3.Distance (transform.position, target.position) <= 0.4f) 
        {
            GetNextWayPoint ();
        }
    }

    void GetNextWayPoint()
    {
        if (wavePointIndex >= Waypoints.points.Length - 1) 
        {
            Destroy (gameObject);
            return;
        }
        wavePointIndex++;
        target = Waypoints.points[wavePointIndex];
    }
}
```

[error description in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Wlm.png)
[Enemy prefab that has script on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EQcK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you uploaded shows that you named `Enemy` script `EnemyMover` in your Editor. This is not a problem but you should always post script names as it is in your scene to avoid confusion.

According to you, this line of code is the problem:  `target = Waypoints.points[0];`

Issue is that `points` is an array of `Transform` and is not initialized.

There are the three possible problems:

**1**.Your `Waypoint` script is NOT attached to the **Waypoints** GameObject. 
Select the **Waypoints** GameObject, drag the `Waypoint` script into it. It must be attached to your **Waypoints** GameObject in order for it to initilize the 
`points` array variable.

**2**.Your `Waypoint` script is attached to multiple GameObjects. Make sure that the `Waypoint` script is ONLY attached to one GameObject and that GameObject is the parent of all your waypoints. This GameObject is named **Waypoints**.

To verify this, select the `Waypoint` script from the Project Tab, right click on it and click **Find Reference In Scene**. It will show you every GameObject the `Waypoint` script is attached to. If it is attached to any GameObject that is not named **Waypoints**, remove the script from that GameObject.

**3**.Functions in your `Waypoint` script are being called before the ones in your `Enemy` script. This happens sometimes in Unity.

Go to **Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Script Execution Order**. Drag the `Waypoint` script into the order then drag the `Enemy` script in the oder. Click Apply.

[image]

Second solution to problem **#3** is to remove the `static` keyword and use `GameObject.Find("Waypoints");` and `GetComponent<Waypoint>();`. You can find complete scripts both scripts [here](http://pastebin.com/5uPsTcxt) and [here](http://pastebin.com/CMSwcpi9). Note that if you follow this second solution of removing the `static` keyword, you may have hard time following the rest of the tutorial.

Comment: the very first solution fixed my problem!
it's always the easy problems that mess with you the most

Comment: Nice. It could be one of those. Don't forget to accept answer.

Comment: I voted for it, but it says I don't have enough points
only just started using this today
thanks a bunch