# Using static function to StartCoroutine to get time from server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

Like the title says I'm trying to get server time. I know there are many other question regarding this issue but none of them helped me. Here the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ServerTime : MonoBehaviour{

    public static ServerTime time;

    void Awake(){
        time = this;
    }

    public static void Get(){
        time.StartCoroutine (time.ServerRequest ());
    }

    IEnumerator ServerRequest(){
        WWW www = new WWW ("http://www.businesssecret.com/something/servertime.php");

        yield return www;

        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }
}
```

And I call it from other script like this:

```
ServerTime.Get();
```

This should print the time from the server but instead I keep getting

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line 13:

```
time.StartCoroutine (time.ServerRequest ());
```

What am I doing wrong? Please don't mark as duplicate because I tried all methods I found from Google and none helped.

Comment: Is your script referenced somewhere? Have a look at Unity Singletons: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should work as it is.

Possible reasons why you are getting that exception:

**1**.You forgot to attach `ServerTime` to an empty GameObject. You must attach it to a GameObject in order for its `Awake()` function to run. When `Awake()` is called, the `time` variable will be initialized.

**2**.You attached `ServerTime` to GameObject but then it got destroyed later on.

**3**.Script Execution order problems in Unity.

The script in which you are calling `ServerTime.Get();` from is loaded before your `ServerTime` script is loaded. This is a know problem in Unity but you can change the [order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39035453/3785314).

The code below should fix all **3** problems described above. If the `time` variable is `null` when `ServerTime.Get()` is called, a new GameObject is created and `ServerTime`  script is attached to it. The `time` is then manually initialized.

```
public class ServerTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static ServerTime localInstance;
    public static ServerTime time { get { return localInstance; } }


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (localInstance != null && localInstance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            localInstance = this;
        }
    }

    public static void Get()
    {
        if (time == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Script not attached to anything");
            GameObject obj = new GameObject("TimeHolder");
            localInstance = obj.AddComponent<ServerTime>();
            Debug.Log("Automatically Attached Script to a GameObject");
        }
        time.StartCoroutine(time.ServerRequest());
    }

    IEnumerator ServerRequest()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("http://www.businesssecret.com/something/servertime.php");

        yield return www;

        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier and more reusable to use the Singleton patern?: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton

Comment: @Ludovic Singleton is not actually the problem. Having multilevel instance of  `ServerTime` will not cause that problem. That's why I didn't mention it. Although, I included a simple singleton in my answer but that's not the problem. It is very likely one of those 3 things I listed.

Comment: Indeed I hadn't attached the script to gameObject. Didn't know I need to do that to get Awake running. Thank you very much.

Comment: No need to check `localInstance != this` in `Awake()`.